# jetpack compose stateflow not refreshing list

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

In my project, I have two fragments.

One is a `normal fragment`, and another is a `bottomSheetDialogFragment`.

In my `normal fragment`, I have a lazyColumn.

I would like to do some settings in the bottomSheetDialogFragment and create a new `Hiit` object and put it into my `hiitItems` list in my `viewmodel`.

**The problem is that** since my `normal fragment` is **partially covered** by the `bottomSheetDialogFragment`, jetpack compose won't re-compose when my list changes.

So I decided to turn to `stateFlow` given that it is always firing, and I assume this might cause recomposition. But unfortunately, it did not.

Below are my codes:

```
// in my viewmodel
// using stateflow to hold the list of hiitItems 
    private var _hiitItems = MutableStateFlow(mutableListOf(HiitItem()))
    val hiitItems = _hiitItems
```

In my `normal fragment`, I'm using composeView to take advantage of `jetpack compose`:

```
 setContent {

// get hiitItems
val hiitItems by vm.hiitItems.collectAsState()
...

 // lazyColumn
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    items(hiitItems) // I'm assuming auto refreshing the list here
    {
     ItemCard(item = it) // ItemCard is just an ordinary composable
    }
 }
}
```

In my `bottomSheetDialogFragment`, I have a button, whose function is to add the newly created hiitItem into my `hiitItems` list, and cause recomposition:

```
 hiitItems.add(newItem)
```

Any idea why the change in my `hiitItems` list is not causing recomposition after I dismiss my bottomSheetDialogFragment?

Comment: I have been stuck for two days for this weird behavior. My two fragments are using the same viewmodel. I also tried the mutableStateOf( listOf() ) approach. Let's say if I put two lazyColunns respectively on each fragment, then the bottom SheetFragment will correctly display my lazyColumn after auto-recomposition, but my partially-covered fragment won't. And it won't show anything when it is no longer covered either, even when these two fragments are using the same reference to a list in my viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved!** Turns out the issue had nothing to do with my `MutableStateFlow`.

It was **viewModel scope** that was causing the failure.

Specifically speaking, my `normal fragment` and `bottomSheetDialogFragment` each has a distinct `viewModel scope`. Therefore, although they did have references to the same viewmodel, the `normal fragment` failed to observe the changes caused by the `bottomSheetDialogFragment`, which is why the recomposition never fired.

For those who might be suffering from a similar issue as I did, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701789/compose-navigation-title-is-not-updating#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20it%27s%20not%20working%20is%20because%20those%20are%20different%20objects%20created%20in%20different%20scopes.) and [this article](https://blog.mindorks.com/shared-viewmodel-in-android-shared-between-fragments#:%7E:text=Shared%20ViewModel%20in%20Android%3A%20Shared%20between%20Fragments) for elabaration!

The takeaway is to make sure that you always acquire the shared viewModel via

```kotlin
val sharedViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

in different fragments where you want to share the same viewmodel scope.

Answer (score 7):

Your mutableStateFlow is not firing because you are mutating the list. Instead of adding an item to the list (mutating it) make a new list with the new item and update your flow with it.

```
private var _hiitItems = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<HittItem>())
```

and later

```
_hiitItems.value = _hiitItems.value + newItem
```

Comment: What about if I want to change a property of an item in the list. Eg update age of an user object. Do you have any suggestions?