# Android update activity with value of data object field from MutableStateFlow<List<MyDataObject>>()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-livedata, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have been having trouble updating my activity/UI layer from my `viewModel()` reliably when I change the value of a field in an object I am using to show a download progress bar. The activity observes the adding and removal of objects from the list fine, but not changes to the progress field.

Data Class

```
data class DownloadObject(
   val id: String?,
   var progress: Float,
)
```

ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel () : ViewModel() {

   private val _progressList = MutableStateFlow<List<DownloadObject>>(emptyList())
   val progressList: StateFlow<List<DownloadObject>>
       get() = _progressList

   //add to list updates the activity
   _progressList.value += DownloadObject

   //remove from list updates the activity
   _progessList.value -= DownloadObject

   // Change progress field doesn't update the activity
   _progressList.value.onEach{
       if(it.id == id) {it.progress = progress}
   }
}
```

Activity

```
val progressList by courseViewModel.progressList.collectAsState(emptyList()
...
LinearProgressIndicator(progress = progressList.find { it.id == id }?.progress)
```

I've tried using `mutableStateListOf()` and `MutableLiveData` but face many of the same issues. I've taken both the state codelabs for compose and am really not sure what to do from here. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: If you wanna your question to be answered, you wanna make time for an expert to get working sample with reproducible problem as fast as possible. Perfectly I should just paste your code into my sample project and see the problem as fast as I run it. In your case I have no idea how do you store/change the `id` and so why `find` may not return `null` for any reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Change progress field doesn't update the activity
   _progressList.value.onEach{
       if(it.id == id) {it.progress = progress}
   }
```

This doesn't actually trigger an update in your `progressList` `StateFlow`.
To do that you'd probably want use something like this:

```
_progressList.value = progressList.value.map {
    if(it.id == id) {
        it.copy(progress = progress)
    } else {
        it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding and removing to your list is actually updating the UI, since you are performing these operations using the '+', and '-' operators, which create a new list, under the hood. Hence, if you want to update the list's contents, then cause a recomposition, you either must do something similar, or change your approach.

For the first option, you can just

```
_progressList.value = progressList.value.onEach{ // Or something of equivalent sort, if Kotlin is smart enough
       if(it.id == id) {it.progress = progress}
   }
```

A better approach is always to use `MutableState` instead of `Flow` or others, when you're working with compose. It is dead clean.

See

```
class MyViewModel () : ViewModel() {

   val progressList = mutableStateListOf<DownloadObject>()

    /* Treat it as a regular list object now*/

   _progressList += DownloadObject

   _progessList.value -= DownloadObject

    // It hopefully will work now
   _progressList.forEach{
       if(it.id == id) {it.progress = progress}
   }
}
```

The Activity:-

```
val progressList by courseViewModel.progressList // That's it
...
LinearProgressIndicator(progress = progressList.find { it.id == id }?.progress)
```

See if it works and let me know

Comment: Thanks but while that does update the contents of the list, it does not trigger a state update that is observable by the activity.

Comment: Which one does not trigger recompositions? The first or the second approach?

Comment: Neither of these approaches will trigger recomposition in the activity. It isn’t an issue of the type of variable I expose to the activity (mutableStateOf, mutableStateListOf, flow, MutableLiveData, etc) I know because I tried them all. The answer I marked correct, mapping then copying with conditions, does work!